# Imagebutton with arrow border

Tags: android, button, view, imagebutton

i want to make a breadcrumb for my android app.
In breadcrumb on the left there is an imagebutton with arrow border. On the right there is a text title. When user tap on imagebutton, application performs specific task.

So, can you help me to create imagebutton with arrow border like in attach image?

Thank you.

[image: My view]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by an Arrow Border, but you cannot (as far as I know) set borders to any views in Android.

There are two options you could go for:

1. Make an outer View to surround the View you want a border on. Then set the background of the outer border to an arrow background.
2. Use a [Nine Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

I would recommend a nine patch for this personally.

Edit: I noticed you wanted a border on an image. That could be an issue with nine patch unless you integrate the border into the image, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'm considering to use extend ImageButton, because ImageButton can have an image and a background. I can't use Nine Patch because button must have fix size.